# Se me detiene el codigo con la sentencia try

Tags: python-3.x

Cuando ejecuto el codigo esta parte se detiene por una excepcion (NoSuchElementException) cuando no puede hacer click en el elemento, todavia no se  mucho de programacion asi que puede que sea muy engorroso el codigo

```
    try:

    DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "INTENTAR DE NUEVO")]').click()
    DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').clear()
    continue

except:

    pass
```

Comment: El `try` no es la causa del error. Nunca lo es.

Comment: El código que publicaste no puede dar ningún error. Ya que, como dice Candid Moe, si lo del try da un error, no dice nada en consola, si no que ejecuta lo que está dentro del except. Y en tu código no haces nada si ocurre un error en el try.

Answer (score 0):

el titulo mas acertado seria "se me detiene el codigo en las sentencias dentro de try"
El error consiste en que selenium no encuentra el elemento que indicaste por medio de la direccion xpath.
No es posible ofrecerte una solucion porque no adjuntas la pagina web para ofrecer alguna opcion.